# What does authenticator for Apache plugin from Certbot actually do for “http-01” challenge?

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, certbot

When using Let’s Encrypt via the Certbot software, you can use the Apache plugin to obtain and install certificates on your Apache web server.

With the “http-01” challenge, which is probably the most popular way to verify your ownership of the domain, the authenticator must somehow serve a file in the directory `/.well-known/acme-challenge` via HTTP on port 80.

But how does Certbot actually do this in an automated way, from a technical perspective?

It seems that Certbot neither changes your virtual host configuration nor the actual contents of the document root for the virtual host.

So how does Certbot technically accomplish its task of serving the file at the required location?

Comment: The normal (non apache plugin): you give the www-root, certbot put a token on the relevant path (relative of the www-root), and when it receive the certificate, it delete the token. For apache I think it is similar, probably without pushing a file (but just a redirect). Being a plug-in of apache it has all information of apache and it can change the asnwers. -- BTW challenges are well documented, and you have the sources of plug-ins, to see the details. Wireshark could help to see the traffic.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, I know about the web root plugin, but when it comes to the Apache plugin, the exact behavior of the challenge is *not* documented, as far as I can see. Apart from that, as noted in the question, the Apache plugin does *not* change “the actual contents of the document root for the virtual host”. So that’s why I have asked how it could serve the `/.well-known/acme-challenge` directory without touching the actual source for its parent directory. Some temporary change to the Apache configuration would have been my guess as well, but I’d love to know the details.

Comment: The challenge it is the same, but the plug-in handle the request. Plug-in will give the data to send (like other plug-in), it doesn't need to write on filesystem. Again "plug-in" into apache. The plug-in is part of the apache process

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-apache/certbot_apache/http_01.py, _mod_config likely contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin's [configurator.py](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-apache/certbot_apache/configurator.py)'s `perform()` calls another perform() in [http_01.py file](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-apache/certbot_apache/http_01.py). This creates the challenge files in the **configured challenge directory, distinct from the document root** (`_set_up_challenges()` includes code to check whether the directory exists and create it). [_mod_config()](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-apache/certbot_apache/http_01.py#L91) then handles serving:

1. Finds or creates a VirtualHost that listens on the configured port and loads configuration data from files (`self._set_up_include_directives(vh)`).
2. Uses the reverter's `register_file_creation()` to [register the creation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/letsencryptkuba/docs/letsencryptkuba.pdf) of temporary _pre and _post rule files (this does not write them, but ensures their deletion if there is a later error).
3. Selects and fills in the configured path of the internal challenge directory in the appropriate pair of `CONFIG_TEMPLATE`s for the configurator being used (e.g., `CONFIG_TEMPLATE22_PRE`) - htaccess rules where the _PRE is a redirect pointing  requests for `.wellknown/acme-challenge/[TOKEN]` to the the challenge directory and the the _POST grants access to both /.wellknown/acme-challenge/ and the challenge directory. Each of these is written to the previously registered location.
4. Declares setup complete and returns.

So yes, a temporary configuration change to redirect requests to a custom directory path.